# Convert String to DataTable using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am trying to convert string to DataTable using the ffollowing method , But It did"nt work

```
public static DataTable convertStringToDataTable(string data)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        bool columnsAdded = false;
        foreach (string row in data.Split('\n'))
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
            {
                string[] keyValue = cell.Split('"');
                if (!columnsAdded)
                {
                    DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn(keyValue[0]);
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
                }
                dataRow[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
            }
            columnsAdded = true;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Code that contains  data string :

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    sw.WriteLine("\"NumClient\",\"Raisons Sociale\",\"DateDocument\",\"NumCommandeNAV\",\"Réference\",\"Designation\",\"QteCommandée\",\"QteLivrée\",\"QteAnnulée\",\"Reste à Livrer\",\"Type Disponibilite\",\"DateDisponibilite\"");

                    var EnTete =
                        db.AURES_GROS_EnTeteCommande.Where(e => e.NumCommandeNAV != " " && e.NumCommandeNAV != "_")
                            .OrderBy(x => x.CodeMagasin)
                            .ThenBy(s => s.NumClient)
                            .ThenBy(c => c.DateDocument)
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.NumCommandeNAV)
                            .ToList();

                    foreach (var element in EnTete)
                    {
                        string statut = RecuperStatut(element.NumCommandeNAV);
                        if (statut == "A livrer")
                        {
                            Raison = context.Users.First(x => x.No_ == element.NumClient).RaisonSociale;
                            lignes = db.AURES_GROS_LigneCommande.Where(x => x.NumDocument == element.NumDocument).ToList();

                        foreach (var elt in lignes)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\",\"{9}\",\"{10}\",\"{11}\"",
                                            element.NumClient,
                                             Raison,
                                             element.DateDocument,
                                             element.NumCommandeNAV,
                                             elt.CodeArticle,
                                             elt.Designation,
                                             elt.Quantite,
                                             0,
                                             elt.QteANNULEE,
                                             elt.Quantite,
                                             element.Couleur,
                                             elt.DateDisponibilite
                                             ));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    DataTable t = convertStringToDataTable(sw.ToString());

                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.BufferOutput = true;
                    Response.ContentType = "text/excel";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Reliquat" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + ".csv");
                    Response.Write(t);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.Close();
                    //Response.End();
```

In this code I want I wnat to export data to Excel file

Any one have solutions
Thanks,

Comment: what you mean by does not work, any error ?

Comment: I got "System.ArgumentException" : The column '' does not belong to the table. " int this line  : dataRow[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a debugger.  When *you* debug this, specifically where does this error happen?  What are the runtime values when it happens?  Why are you looking for a column with an empty string as its name?

Comment: the problem is that at this line `keyvalue[1]` is `empty`.  Debug your code .you will easy understand what's the problem in your code.

Comment: After Debugging , I found that  DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn(keyValue[0]); always return null even keyValue[0] doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your column foreach to a for loop.

```
public static DataTable convertStringToDataTable(string data)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        bool columnsAdded = false;
        foreach (string row in data.Split('\n'))
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            string[] cell = row.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < cell.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] keyValue = cell[i].Split('"');
                if (!columnsAdded)
                {
                    DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn();
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
                }
                dataRow[i] = keyValue[1];
            }
            columnsAdded = true;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

However if your split string[] keyValue = cell.Split('"'); is not returning what you are expecting you may need to investigate further.

Comment: THANKS Scrobi for replying an dtrying to help me

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to create a DataTable from a string. So first split the "rows" and then the "columns". You are adding the DataColumns in the row-loop. You need that only once before the loop. Here is another implementation which handles this and other edge cases you haven't considered yet:

```
public static DataTable ConvertStringToDataTable(string data)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    // extract all lines:
    string[] lines = data.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string header = lines.FirstOrDefault();
    if (header == null)
        return dataTable;
    // first create the columns:
    string[] columns = header.Split(','); // using commas as delimiter is brave ;)
    foreach (string col in columns)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(col.Trim());

    foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
    {
        string[] fields = line.Split(',');
        if(fields.Length != dataTable.Columns.Count)
            continue; // should not happen

        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.Rows.Add();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
            dataRow.SetField(i, fields[i]);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: Nice comment about the delimiter, they'll find out about that later I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks Tim for replying , I got an Exception , I am trying to fixe it

Comment: @Sarra: i'd try to help if you'd mention it.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim , I am beginner in english , maybe I can"t express very well , Sorry for any misunderstood

Comment: @Sarra: no, you've misunderstood me. I would try to fix this exception if you would mention it. What is the exception-message, what is it's `StackTrace`(including line number).

Comment: aa ok  :p , I fixed the exception , it was because the number of column no equals to the number of data , but Now DataTable returned is null,after debbuging , lines and columns  and header are full but the result DataTable is empty

Comment: @Sarra: What code are you using and what is the sample `data`-string? I also don't understand why your code had a problem with column-numbers because my code handles that: `if(fields.Length != dataTable.Columns.Count)
            continue;`

Comment: the code that contains data string is added with question , have a look at it

Comment: Before you write the `DataTable` to the response stream, is the content of the table correct(checked with a debugger)? Then it's a different question.

Comment: table is empty befor the response